# SDL fail to load media using files and headers

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I just started following Lazy [Foo's SDL tutorial](http://www.lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/02_getting_an_image_on_the_screen/index.php). My question regards the code in lesson 02, so I assume this is quite basic. I have to say that I don't have too much C++ experience either!

The code provided by Lazy Foo works fine in my machine (Windows-Code::Blocks). However, as an exercise I tried to move the example's functions to a separate file (with the corresponding header file). I also moved variables into main, so as to avoid globals. The only real change I needed to implement was to include some input variables for my functions, since I would not be relying on globals.

My code compiles, but it fails to upload the image as required. Here you have the code of the simple function:

```
bool loadMedia(SDL_Surface* gHelloWorld) {
//Loading success flag
bool success = true;

//Load splash image
gHelloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP("hello_world.bmp");
if(gHelloWorld == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to load image %s! SDL Error: %s\n", "hello_world.bmp",
        SDL_GetError());
    success = false;
}

return success;
```

And this is the bit where I call that function:

```
    if(!loadMedia(gHelloWorld)) {
        printf( "Failed to load media!\n" );
    } else {
        //Apply the image
        SDL_BlitSurface( gHelloWorld, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );

        //Update the surface
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );

        //Wait two seconds
        SDL_Delay( 2000 );
    }
```

Using the debugger I noticed gHelloWorld never updates its value, unlike in the original example given by Lazy Foo. Since gHelloWorld is a pointer I believed this should work fine.

What is going on here?

Thank you very much for your help!

Pablo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another pointer level to actually modify the variable in the calling function:

```
bool loadMedia(SDL_Surface** gHelloWorld) {
    ...
    *gHelloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP("hello_world.bmp");
    if(*gHelloWorld == NULL) {
    ...
```

and call it like this:

```
SDL_Surface *gHelloWorld;
if(!loadMedia(&gHelloWorld)) {
```

Explanation: In C, there is little to no behind-the-scenes magic when using pointers. `SDL_LoadBMP` creates a new `SDL_Surface` and returns a *pointer* to that surface. Your function only stored that pointer (i.e. the address) in a local variable, but did *not* not modify the variable in the calling function. To do that, you need to pass the *address* of the variable in the calling function using the `&` operator, and store the value in the pointer at that address, using `*`.

The code in lazy foo's example worked because `gHelloWorld` is a global variable there.

Since you are using C++, you could also use reference parameters (which do a little behind-the-scenes magic).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did try something like that, but I guess I messed up. I need some practice with pointers yet!

Comment: Just in case someone is in the exact same problem: I had to apply the same changes in function init, otherwise the program would work but only display a white window.